# Pulling All Rows From Database for the Same User

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I've copied and pasted every possible method suggested how to pull all the rows for one user then echo out unto another page, but cannot get it to echo out anything. The code is not giving me error just blank where I include_once the PHP page.

```
<?php
$userid  = 10;  

/****************************************************************
* Open connection to the MySQL database
****************************************************************/

// Create new mysqli object representing a connection to the MySQL data
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "db");

// Test if a connection error occurred
if ($mysqli->connect_errno !=0)  {
    exit;
}

/**************************************************************
* Run an SQL statement
**************************************************************/

// Create an INSERT query  
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE(userid='".$userid."')";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $category = $row['category'];
        $amount   = $row['amount'];
        echo $category;
    }
    $result->close();
}
//  Attempt to close connection
$closed = $mysqli->close();
?>
```

This user has 10 rows of content and I would like to pull all out, please assist!

Comment: Why are you running the query twice, and running two separate loops? You could combine the while+foreach loops and simply have `echo $rows['category']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE(userid='".$userid."')";
```

Should be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE userid='".$userid."'";
```

Also there is an error here

```
while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

     $rows[] = $row;
    }
```

**$row** is not defined, so you should assign **$rows** to your array on left. name the left array something else, like

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $values[] = $rows;
    }
    foreach($values as $row) {
        $category = $row['category'];
        $amount   = $row['amount'];
        echo $category;
    }
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: @JW.: You are missing a space

Comment: @juergend did you test it yourself? still it will work, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/879e0/14

Answer (score 0):

Review your code for possible point failures, some notes below.
If you learning why not take a look at PHP PDO class that would be a nice replacement for several database drivers.

```
<?php

  $userid  = 10;  


  /****************************************************************
   * Open connection to the MySQL database
   ****************************************************************/

   // Create new mysqli object representing a connection to the MySQL data
   $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "db");


   // Test if a connection error occurred
   if ( $mysqli->connect_errno != 0 )
    exit( 'error on connect' );

     /**************************************************************
    * Run an SQL statement
    **************************************************************/

    // Create an INSERT query  

    // avoid temporary variables
    //$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE(userid='".$userid."')";
    // reader will know taht is a query by function name
    //WARNING you should scape data coming from form
    //expecting numeric data, so convert it
    $result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE(userid='".intval( $userid )."')" );

    // error here
    //if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    //
    if ( !($result = $mysqli->query($result)) )
      exit( 'query error' );
    // error here also changed variable name
    //while ($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
    // $rows[] = $row;
    $rows = array();
    while ( $tmp = $result->fetch_assoc() )
     $rows[] = $tmp;

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
     // unnecessary code also, duplicating variable
     //$category  = $row['category'];
     //$amount    = $row['amount'];
     //echo $category;
      echo $row['category'];
    } 

     $result->close();
    }


//  Attempt to close connection
$closed = $mysqli->close();
?>
```